# Angular - communication between services with observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service with a method where I emit an observable, then in another service I want to subscribe to that observable, what's the best way to do this?

```
aServiceMethod(value){
      this.serviceA.obs$.next(value);
}

bServiceMethod(){
    let method B = //get value from obs
}
```

Subscribe the observable in bServiceMethod and use take(1)?

Subscribe the observable in the constructor of service B?

Transform the observable into behaviorSubject and use getValue()?

Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a `BehaviorSubject` here would be the best strategy to keep track of the value of interest globally (between the different services)

Emitting the value from the `aServiceMethod` method, in the tune of:

```
export class ServiceA {
  obs$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  aServiceMethod(value: any){
    this.obs$.next(value);
  }
}
```

and subscribing to the observable in `bServiceMethod`:

```
export class ServiceB {
  constructor(private serviceA: ServiceA) {
    this.bServiceMethod();
  }

  bServiceMethod() {
    this.serviceA.obs$.subscribe(value => {
      let methodB = value;
      console.log(methodB);
    });
  }
}
```